# Augmented Reality - Distance between marker image and Camera in ArKit?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to calculate the distance between any marker image saved in the iOS project which is used for detecting in Augmented Reality and your current position i.e. camera position using ARKIT ?

Comment: Pls share what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Apple’s [documentation and sample code](http://developer.apple.com/arkit) note:

- A detected image is reported to your app as an [`ARImageAnchor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimageanchor) object.
- `ARImageAnchor` is a subclass of [`ARAnchor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor).
- `ARAnchor` has a `transform` property, which indicates its position and orientation in 3D space.
- ARKit also provides you an [`ARCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera) on every frame (or you can get it from the session’s `currentFrame`).
- `ARCamera` also has a `transform` property, indicating the camera’s position and orientation in 3D space.
- You can get the [translation vector (position) from a 4x4 transform matrix](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72044) by extracting the last column vector.

That should be enough for you to connect the dots...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SceneKit and have the `SCNNode*` that came with

`-(void) renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor*)anchor`

then

`[node convertPosition:{0,0,0} toNode:self.sceneView.pointOfView].z`

is distance to camera.